# how can automatically indent code use tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

i have 3 questions.

1. how can justify low part of below code center and flushleft?
2. how can customize keyword of maple in low part automatically?
3. how auto indent code automatically?

code is:

```
‎\documentclass{article}‎

‎\usepackage{tcolorbox}‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}‎

‎\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,theorems}‎

‎\lstdefinelanguage{Maple}{‎
            ‎morekeywords={‎
            ‎and,assuming,break,by,catch,description,do,done‎,
            ‎elif,else,end,error,export,fi,finally,for,from,global,if‎,
            ‎implies,in,intersect,local,minus,mod,module,next,not,od‎,
            ‎option,options,or,proc,quit,read,return,save,stop,subset,then‎,
            ‎to,try,union,use,uses,while,xor‎
            ‎}‎,
            ‎sensitive=true‎,
            ‎keywordstyle=\color{black}‎,
            ‎morecomment=[l][\color{green!50!black}]\#‎,
            ‎morestring=[b]"‎,
            ‎morestring=[d]‎"
            ‎aboveskip={0pt}‎,
            ‎belowskip={0pt}‎,
            ‎}[keywords,comments,strings]‎

‎\newtcblisting{code}[1]{‎
             ‎skin=bicolor‎,
             ‎colback=white‎,
             ‎colbacklower=white‎,
             ‎colupper=red!40!black‎,
             ‎collower=black‎,
             ‎listing options={language={Maple}}‎,
             ‎fontupper=\ttfamily\bfseries‎,
             ‎fontlower=\itshape‎,
%             ‎fontlower=\rm\bf‎,
%            ‎math lower‎,
             ‎boxrule=0mm‎,
             ‎top=0mm,bottom=0mm,middle=0mm‎,
             ‎center lower‎,
%             ‎flushleft lower‎,
             ‎nobeforeafter‎, 
           ‎listing and comment‎,
           ‎comment={ #1}‎,
           ‎every listing line={\textcolor{red!40!black}{\ttfamily>‎ }}
           }

‎\begin{document}‎



‎\begin{code}{‎
‎Fib‎‎ :‎= ‎proc‎(‎‎n::nonnegint)\\‎
option remember; system;\\‎
if $n < 2$ then $n$ else ‎Fib‎$‎(n‎ - ‎1)‎‎$‎ + ‎Fib‎$‎(n‎ - ‎2)$ end if\\‎
‎end proc‎
}
‎Fib‎ :‎= proc( n‎ :: ‎nonnegint‎ )
‎option remember‎, ‎system;‎
‎if n<2 then‎
‎n‎
‎else‎
‎Fib(n-1)‎ + ‎Fib(n-2)‎
‎end if;‎
‎end proc;‎
‎\end{code}‎


‎\end{document}
```

output is:
[image]

i want:
[image]

Comment: I do not know a way to format and indent pseudocode with LaTeX automatically. And I'm very sure that `tcolorbox` cannot do such things - code formatting is done with `listings` or `minted` when using `tcolorbox`. The pseudocode could be formatted manually with packages like [algorithm2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e), but not automatically.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm, thanks for answer, i want a way to justify center, and flushleft the result. when use "‎center lower‎", output isn't what i want.

Comment: I added an answer to show one possibility.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know a way to format and indent pseudocode with LaTeX automatically. And I'm very sure that `tcolorbox` cannot do such things - code formatting is done with listings or `minted` when using `tcolorbox`. The pseudocode could be formatted manually with packages like [algorithm2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e), but not automatically.

To get a left justified block which is centered, the content has to be put into some left justified box which is centered afterwards.

One way to achieve the desired output without additional packages is to put the pseudocode into a table and format the keyword by an easy macro like `\mykw`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,theorems}

\lstdefinelanguage{Maple}{
            morekeywords={
            and,assuming,break,by,catch,description,do,done,
            elif,else,end,error,export,fi,finally,for,from,global,if,
            implies,in,intersect,local,minus,mod,module,next,not,od,
            option,options,or,proc,quit,read,return,save,stop,subset,then,
            to,try,union,use,uses,while,xor
            },
            sensitive=true,
            keywordstyle=\color{black},
            morecomment=[l][\color{green!50!black}]\#,
            morestring=[b]",
            morestring=[d]"
            aboveskip={0pt},
            belowskip={0pt},
            }[keywords,comments,strings]

\newtcblisting{code}[1]{
             skin=bicolor,
             colback=white,
             colbacklower=white,
             colupper=red!40!black,
             collower=black,
             listing options={language={Maple}},
             fontupper=\ttfamily\bfseries,
             fontlower=\itshape,
%             fontlower=\rm\bf,
%            math lower,
             boxrule=0mm,
             top=0mm,bottom=0mm,middle=0mm,
             center lower,
%             flushleft lower,
             nobeforeafter,
           listing and comment,
           comment={ #1},
           every listing line={\textcolor{red!40!black}{\ttfamily> }}
           }

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mykw}[1]{\textbf{\upshape #1}}

\begin{code}{
\begin{tabular}{l}
Fib := \mykw{proc}(n::nonnegint)\\
\mykw{option} remember; system;\\
\hspace{4mm}\mykw{if} $n < 2$ \mykw{then} $n$ \mykw{else} Fib$(n - 1)$ + Fib$(n - 2)$ \mykw{end if}\\
\mykw{end proc}
\end{tabular}
}
Fib := proc( n :: nonnegint )
option remember, system;
if n<2 then
n
else
Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)
end if;
end proc;
\end{code}


\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do not repeat "\begin{code}{\begin{tabular}{l}" and "\end{tabular}}" ? i mean, add \begin{tabular}{l} and \end{tabular} automatically?

Comment: found it, if use
comment={\begin{tabular}{‎l}‎#1\end{‎tabular}‎},
don't necessary add tabular env to all.